# Get ion.rangeslider value, multiple by price and total all sliders at bottom

Tags: jquery, rangeslider

Working on this codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RrEbjB

Each slider is $15 each, I need to get the sliders when adjusted to update the total at the bottom.  All 3 should apply to the main total.

Any help is appreciated on getting the callback to work, I removed the code I was working on as it just broke everything...

```
$(function () {

    $("#range1").ionRangeSlider({
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        hide_min_max: true
    });

    $("#range2").ionRangeSlider({
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        hide_min_max: true
    });

    $("#range3").ionRangeSlider({
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        hide_min_max: true
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured for the sake of other users, I would post the code that worked for me in the end.

```
function sum () {
    var total = (a * 15) + (b * 15) + (c * 15);
    $total.text(total);
}

function sum2 () {
    var totals = (a * 15) + (b * 15) + (c * 15);
    var k = Number(totals) + Number( $('#other_amount').val());
    $grand_total.text(k);
}

$('#other_amount').change(function() {
    sum2();
});

$("#range1").ionRangeSlider({
    min: 0,
    max: 25,
    postfix: " in Basket",
    hide_min_max: true,
    hide_from_to: false,
    grid: true,
    keyboard: true,
    keyboard_step: 1,
    force_edges: true,
    onChange: function (data) {
        a = data.from;
        sum();
        sum2();
    }
});

$("#range2").ionRangeSlider({
    min: 0,
    max: 25,
    postfix: " in Basket",
    hide_min_max: true,
    hide_from_to: false,
    grid: true,
    keyboard: true,
    keyboard_step: 1,
    force_edges: true,
    onChange: function (data) {
        b = data.from;
        sum();
        sum2();
    }
});

$("#range3").ionRangeSlider({
    min: 0,
    max: 25,
    postfix: " in Basket",
    hide_min_max: true,
    hide_from_to: false,
    grid: true,
    keyboard: true,
    keyboard_step: 1,
    force_edges: true,
    onChange: function (data) {
        c = data.from;
        sum();
        sum2();
    }
});
```